# How to update single application like VLC only?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, update-manager

I want to update only one Application like VLC or Firefox instead of upgrading all applications.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

above command will update all the application, but I want only one particular application to be update.

Using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on HP 15 R006TX Notebook PC.

Answer (score 3):

`sudo apt-get install vlc` will install OR upgrade vlc

Answer (score 1):

Try the command below to upgrade vlc only.

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install vlc
```